# updating multiple rows in one sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to update an arbitrary number of rows for a list of customers, when reminders are sent out to them. I can achieve this through a foreach loop, but I am sure there must be a way of doing this with on query.

This is what currently works

```
foreach($customer_id_arr as $c) mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crm_customers SET customer_reminded=1 WHERE customer_id=$c");
```

How can I do that in one query?

Comment: Use SQL `Where customer_id  In (...)`

Comment: the pattern is: `where customer_id in (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: You are most likely vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use prepared statements!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode) for this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crm_customers SET customer_reminded=1 WHERE customer_id IN (" . implode(",",$customer_id_arr) . ")";
```

It's worth mentioning that you're likely wide open to SQL injection without using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: oh wow, yes, of course, I should have worked that out! Thanks

Comment: @Nick Actually learned this very recentlty but `implode`'s parameters may be swapped (the doc does mention it). Still bad practice, especially since `explode` doesn't allow it, but may be useful to be aware of :)

Comment: @Jeto yeah, you are correct, I've pushed that information to the far recesses of my mind as it's a bad habit and we all try *so hard* not to have any of them! :-)

Comment: @esqew my apologies, your original code would work, as Jeto pointed out `implode` will take its parameters in either order.

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest way to escape data, but you can do:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE 
    crm_customers 
  SET 
    customer_reminded=1 
  WHERE customer_id IN (".implode(',', array_map(function($c){return $con->real_escape_string($c);a},$customer_id_arr)).")");
```

Comment: don't mix mysqli_ and mysql_ functions

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need to update customer ID's 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5:

```
UPDATE crm_customers 
SET customer_reminded = 1 
WHERE customer_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

You could even use subqueries in your IN clause.  Let's say you wanted to set customer_reminded=1 on all records where customer_reminded==0.  Something like:

```
UPDATE crm_customers SET customer_reminded = 1 
WHERE customer_id IN 
    (SELECT customer_id 
    FROM crm_customers 
    WHERE customer_reminded == 0)
```